# Identifying cause of frames dropping using CSS3 animations

Tags: angularjs, css, animation

I'm trying to identify the cause of extreme slowdown in animations. As you can see (below) the paint times occasionally spike and cause the frames rate to drop to < 15 fps.

I can't show the site, but I can tell you that it's **not** lightweight on the front-end, it's a design showcase site, so there are plenty of large images animating in from outside of the view-port. I need to establish whether this is just something they're going to have to deal with or if anything can be done to reduce the paint times.

All of the animations are achieved using the `translate()` functions. The CSS for this particular set of animations follow:

```
.page {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute !important;

    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);

    /**
     * Override ng-animate-block-transition on this element. Has an important declaration.
     */
    -webkit-transition: transform ease-in-out 0.5s !important;
    transition: transform ease-in-out 0.5s !important;
}

.page.ng-show {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}

.animate-in-enter-complete .page-peak .page.ng-show {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-3%);
    transform: translateY(-3%);
}

.animate-in-enter-complete .page-peak .page.page-next {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(95%);
    transform: translateY(95%);
}
```

And here is a profile, which I did for this particular animation. The layer root is `#document`, I'm kind of new to these tools, but does that mean it's re-painting the entire DOM tree?

How can I find out what is causing that?

[image: Screenshot of profiling tools]

Comment: I think that will be very hard to tell what's going on here without being able to see it in action... Maybe you could reproduce a simple fiddle showing the same issue ?

Comment: It's a very complicated site, I don't think I will be able to reproduce the issue in a fiddle. I won't be able to show any kind of demo until it releases, though I will see if I can give it a go later today. I was more looking for a more "how do I go about finding the root cause?".

Comment: Ho ok... Do you know anything about the continuous repainting mod ? In the developer tools, you have an option called "enable continuous page repainting" (in my case in a "Rendering" tab). If you check it, you will now see a time graph up right. Then show/hide some DOM, enable/disable some CSS rules, and see what is taking so long to repaint. You have a good post explaining it [here](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/02/Profiling-Long-Paint-Times-with-DevTools-Continuous-Painting-Mode)

Comment: Just for the sake of testing, try to provide fixed values to the transition methods instead of percentages. Would be interesting to know if that changes performance in any way

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Optimization is just guessing without having a page to look at, but I can give you some thoughts that might be useful.

The CSS `transform` and `opacity` properties do not trigger layout or paint. It doesn’t matter if the animation is handled by JavaScript or CSS. Something else than the `transform` must be causing it. A full list of the work triggered by individual CSS properties can be found at [CSS Triggers](http://csstriggers.com/), and you can find a full guide on creating [High Performance Animations](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/) on HTML5 Rocks. My guess is that you can do a lot of render tree, layout and paint optimization.

Use `will-change` to ensure that the browser knows what you plan to animate. The will-change property allows you to inform the browser ahead of time of what kinds of changes you are likely to make to an element, so that it can set up the appropriate optimizations before they’re needed. The elements can be changed and rendered faster, resulting in a smoother experience. In the case of your sample, adding will-change for transforms looks like this:

```
.page {
  will-change: transform;
}
```

Note: Do not use `will-change` on too many elements, it will cause the opposite. Currently Chrome, Firefox and Opera support this feature. It seems to get support from all modern browsers [in the future](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/LwvyVCMQx1k).

Comment: +1 for suggesting `will-change` :) however, in light that many users today still use browsers that do not understand that property, you can also force compositing in GPU using `translate3D` or even `translateZ`.

Comment: Also, Opera published a really good overview of the `will-change` property: https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-will-change-property/ A great read I'd say ;)

Comment: Thanks, I just need some starting pointers. I'm fully aware that it's really hard to guess at the solution but it's borderline impossible for me to recreate this problem in a sandbox and the site doesn't launch for another 2-3 weeks. Sorry but the best I can do right now is provide more details, screenshots, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't gotten a chance to actually test but yours has some of the best advice going forwards, which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Some new CSS3 features can be really heavy :

- `box-shadow` combined with `border-radius`
- `filter` (grayscale, blur, contrast, ...)
- `transform`
- ...

By enabling continuous repainting, you can see what rule is causing this load when disabling it. See [this post](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/02/Profiling-Long-Paint-Times-with-DevTools-Continuous-Painting-Mode)

If you find that it is the transformation that is causing this load, that might be because the hardware acceleration is not used by the browser. You can force it by using 3D rendering that will not affect your transformation. One of these rules may do the trick :

```
transform: translateZ(0);
/* or */
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
/* or */
perspective: 1000; 
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

If not, you may rethink your integration by wondering if the rule causing the load is actually essential.

Comment: Thanks, I need a couple of days to test this out and debug. I'll get back to you and let you know how it's going.

Answer (score 2):

23 seconds to paint one image is a bit too much. They don't need to *"deal with it"*, just to find the bug. Because *there is* a bug, in the code, in the design (2337 images in a page, for example), or somewhere else.

Without being able to see the site, nor an anonymous fiddle reproducing its behaviour, nor even the HTML (!), and without knowing the number of images, their size, etc... the only possible answer left is:

[image]

Comment: I think you misread. It's not 23 seconds to paint, that would be ludicrous! It's 48.603ms for the paint, the problem is that this happens quite often in a short period of time and this causes frames to drop quite badly.

And yes I appreciate it's hard to tell what's going on without being able to see it, but the site doesn't launch for another 2 weeks and I don't think I could produce an accurate demo without recreating the entire site in codepen or plunkr.

Comment: Ahah, definitely misread :) thousandths of milliseconds, Nice tool! You should try to reproduce only the relevant carousel (or whatever) in a fiddle, otherwise the crystal ball is still our best option, BTW :/